# .htacess custom redirect rules conflicting with Wordpress redirect rules

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am in the process of moving my current static site to Wordpress, using the same domain name.

Both old and new sites have their content in the root folder and also have identical file names, but on the new (Wordpress) site, I have removed the .php extension that exists on the current site and added a trailing slash, as per Wordpress permalinks.

So I need to redirect all the old pages (for example):
/contact-us.php -> /contact-us/

I have tried the well-documented options such as (and variations on this):

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

But this seems to be conflicting with the Wordpress .htaccess rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

When I try to access www.site.com/contact-us.php, I am getting either an infinite loop OR a redirect to www.site.com/index (no .php, no trailing slash), which Wordpress displays as a 404 page.

I have tried with and without the first set of Rewrite conditions (as I see they are duplicated in the Wordpress rules), and also placed my rule before and after the Wordpress rules. No joy. I've also been Googling for the last few hours but no one seems to have addressed this specific problem. I do usually find what I am looking for by searching, so it's in desperation that I'm actually posting (and which is why it's my first post!)

If anyone can help out, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you will run into loops when trying an .htaccess redirect because of the php suffix. Maybe someone else knows a solution.

But try a plugin called [Redirection « WordPress Plugins.](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/) Out of curiosity, I tried a redirect from contact-us.php to contact-us/ and it worked fine. The plugin redirects via php rather than writing to .htaccess, and that may be the difference.

I use the plugin all the time to mostly log 404's and do a few redirects. It doesn't take too much site overhead.

Be sure and set Options to not do "URL Monitoring," as that will set up automatic redirects to  to posts/pages that have their permalinks manually changed. And set your 404 logging to a day or two, because the logs can quickly get big and result in huge database tables.

Comment: Great! I had actually tried this plugin and others too, but they weren't working for me - I now see it was a browser cache issue. I've set up Redirection again with a single regex rule, cleared the cache and it's working fine thus far. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /

 #Rewrite /something.php to /something/
 RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)\.php$ $1/$2/ [R=301,L]

 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
 </IfModule>
```

This method would rewrite:
`/contact-us/test/hello.php` -> `/contact-us/test/hello/`

If you don't want subdirectory rewriting replace line 6 with:

`RewriteRule /(.*)\.php$ /$1/ [R=301,L]`

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but it is sending me to /index again, with a 404 message. I've been reading more and apparently the issue is that Wordpress uses the index.php file as a "front-end controller" for all permalinks. If you know any way around this, it would be great - I'd rather use the htaccess file than php redirection.